# I'd like to change vs-unit-testing-framework TimeoutAttribute result from Timeout to Passed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to test Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TimeoutAttribute.
Yes, I'm trying to test the attribute itself: [Timeout(1000)]

In the small sample below, the timeout attribute works as expected.  The timeout attribute stops the test method after 1 second.  This is the expected behavior and timeouts the test with a message: 'msUTF_T1_TimeoutTest2' exceeded execution timeout period.

This is the behavior I want/expect (the Timeout attribute stopped execution of the test before the test completed).  I'm testing that the Timeout attribute worked correctly, so I want change the UnitTestOutcome from Timeout to Passed.

Any thoughts?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace MSUnitTestFrameworkTests
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    [TestClass()]
    public class UnitTestFrameworkTests
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Test the Timeout(Int32) Attribute
        /// It is expected that the test SHOULD timeout before completing since the Thread.Sleep() is
        /// longer that the test timeout value, Timeout is the correct behavior, change it to Passed.
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod, Timeout(1000)]
        public void msUTF_T1_TimeoutTest2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // always fail if it gets here, means that it didn't time out correctly
            Assert.Fail("Timeout attribute should have triggered.  This assert should never be reached ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing this?  It is generally always accepted as the frameworks your working with should themselves be tested, and you should not be testing them.  Especially when it comes to unit testing.

Comment: In some regulated environments, you need to qualify the tools you are using.  So, I need to test the Timeout attribute and prove that it works as expected.  Obviously, it does and can be proved manually by observation.  I'm trying to do this, plus others, in an automated test.

Comment: To update, Google Test has what I was looking for with EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE() and EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE() constructs.